# Boolean logic anomaly in Swift?

Tags: swift, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

:I've encountered something I can't explain in the following code:

```
        let isEmptyString = reminderNotesTextInput.text == ""
        print(isEmptyString)        // TRUE
        let isNilNote = reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil
        print(isNilNote)            // TRUE
        print((reminderNotesTextInput.text == "") && (reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil))  // FALSE!!!!!!!!
        if (reminderNotesTextInput.text == "") && (reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil) {
            print("this doesn't get executed")
        }
        print(isEmptyString && isNilNote)   // TRUE
```

reminderNotesTextInput is a UITextView. reminderWrapper is a wrapper class for an EKReminder (i.e., it has a property called reminder of type EKReminder):

```
// Needed for the Equatable protocol
func ==(lhs: ReminderWrapper, rhs: ReminderWrapper) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}

class ReminderWrapper: Equatable {
    var name: String
    var reminder: EKReminder

    init(name: String, reminder: EKReminder) {
        self.name = name
        self.reminder = reminder
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I got it working. But I don't understand why this now works.

```
    let isEmptyString = reminderNotesTextInput.text.isEmpty
    print(isEmptyString)        // TRUE
    let isNilNote = reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil
    print(isNilNote)            // TRUE
    print((reminderNotesTextInput.text.isEmpty) && (reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil))  // THIS NOW IS ALSO TRUE!!!!!!!!
```

I would've thought that `someString.isEmpty` is syntactic sugar for `someString == ""`. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you boil this down into a [minimal, complete and **verifiable** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us? Since we have neither `reminderNotesTextInput` or `reminderWrapper`, we can't easily reproduce this.

Comment: I added code for ReminderWrapper. As said, reminderNotesTextInput is a UITextView in my storyboard. There can't be any side effects in the code snippet I posted yet something strange is happening...

Comment: have you tried moving `(reminderNotesTextInput.text == " ") && (reminderWrapper?.reminder.notes == nil)` into an if statement to see if it returns false there as well?

Comment: And have you tried it with `isEmptyString && isNilNote` ?

Comment: Yes. Pls. see the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

On "strange" behaviours, **always**, make tests on simple forms.
Check in playground:

```
let a = "" // ""
let b = Optional<String>.None // nil

a == "" && b == nil // true
a.isEmpty && b == nil // true
```

**Apple Swift version 2.1.1**

Comment: Agreed. However, this doesn't explain the strange behaviour itself. Why isn't == "" the same as isEmpty?

Comment: @Daniel the same. `a.isEmpty && a == "" // true`.
Also: isEmpty – "true" iff "self" contains no characters.